# Вывести первой запись с определенной меткой

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress

На странице выведены посты, как можно вывести пост первым, если ему присвоена определенная метка.

Например если посту присвоить метку winter, значит его нужно вывести в самом верху

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сортировку по меткам считают не логичной и это обсуждалось в этом вопросе https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14306/using-wp-query-is-it-possible-to-orderby-taxonomy Но если вы считаете, что в вашем случае все по-другому, то можете использовать 2 цикла. В первом проверить метку и вывести все посты, которые принадлежат метке и удалить из wp_query->posts, а во втором вывести все оставшиеся.